# why does json-server only work on localhost server?

Tags: api, url, localhost, json-server

I have an app where I used json-server to create a quick backend for me to test. My app now works the way  I want it to, but I realized that my app doesn't work on other laptops/phones because my json-server uses localhost. Can json-server work with custom URLs, or does it only work on localhost? Do I have to start over and use a different backend? If so, does anyone have suggestions for which backend I should use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your backend on a cellphone or another thing you need two things

### First

Your server and your client, in this case the cellphone both of them needs to be connected on the same wifi aka Local network

## Second

Yow backend instead of pointing to localhost you need to specify the ip of your computer

`json-server --host 192.168.0.xx file.json --port 4000`